# How to hollow out this surface?

Tags: plotting, textures

Recently I am replaying with this (I made it in the past):

[image: hyperboloid with holes]

the theory is `Texture` in Mathematica (map the vertex(x,y) to curve(u,v), and draw polygons). So I decided to make it with Mathematica.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Cos[v], 
  Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Sin[v], -u}, {u, -8, 8}, {v, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[
    MengerMesh[4] // Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 600] & // 
     ImageTrim[#, {{0, 0} + 13, {600, 600} - 13}] &]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

Now I want to hollow out this surface. How to do it?

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ColorReplace[]` to inject transparency into a texture is very useful for this sort of thing:

```
sierp = ColorReplace[Rasterize[Show[MengerMesh[4, MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Gray,
                                                                    {2, All} -> Gray}],
                                    ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None],
                               RasterSize -> 600], White];

ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Cos[v], Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Sin[v], -u},
                 {u, -8, 8}, {v, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False,
                 PlotStyle -> {Texture[sierp]}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: hyperboloid with Sierpinski holes]

Answer (score 5):

Expanding cvgmt's answer, there is a perfect result within 10 seconds in my macbook.

Let's unwrap uv to plane,[Here is done by Sow/Reap u,v] and then choose polygons in Region.

```
reg=TransformedRegion[MengerMesh[4],{Rescale[Indexed[#,1],{0,1},{0,2Pi}],Rescale[Indexed[#,2],{0,1},{0,\[Pi]}]}&]
AbsoluteTiming[c=0;r=Reap[surf=ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]Sin[v],Cos[u]Cos[v],Sin[u]}(*{Sqrt[u^2-1] Cos[v],Sqrt[u^2-1] Sin[v],-u}*),{u,0,2\[Pi]},{v,0,\[Pi]},RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z,u,v},Sow[{{x,y,z},{u,v}}];True],PlotPoints->100,MaxRecursion->2,Boxed->False,Axes->False,Mesh->False,ColorFunction->(ColorData["Rainbow"][#2]&)]];]
pts=Flatten[r[[2,1]][[All,1]],0];
pts//Length
uv=r[[2,1]][[All,2]];
uv//Length
AbsoluteTiming[tfList=RegionMember[reg,uv];]
tfList//Counts
pts2Plot=Pick[pts,tfList];
mesh=DiscretizeGraphics@r[[1]];
polygons=MeshPrimitives[mesh,2];
polygons//Length
meshPoint=DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics3D[Point/@pts2Plot];
AbsoluteTiming[polygons2Use=Select[polygons[[1;;-1]],Or@@RegionMember[meshPoint,#[[1]]]&];]
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],polygons2Use,Red,meshPoint}]
```

[image]
[image]

---

**Update**

The above method is limited, since the sampling problem of `ParametricPlot3D`
[image]

So we can plot it with `Graphics3D`

[image]

```
reg=MengerMesh[4,DataRange->{{-8,8},{0,2\[Pi]}}];
polygons=MeshCells[reg,2];
coo=MeshCoordinates[reg];
pts2Use=Table[{u,v}=p;{Sqrt[u^2-1] Cos[v],Sqrt[u^2-1] Sin[v],-u},{p,coo}];
pts2UseReal=If[AnyTrue[Head/@#,#===Complex&],{0,0,0},#]&/@pts2Use;
gc=GraphicsComplex[pts2UseReal,polygons];
Graphics3D@gc
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add the option `Background -> None` in `Rasterize`:

```
mm = Rasterize[MengerMesh[4, MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Gray, {2, All} -> Gray}, 
     ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   RasterSize -> 900, Background -> None];

ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Cos[v], Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Sin[v], -u}, 
 {u, -8, 8}, {v, 0, 2 π}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> Texture[mm], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Use `Texture[ImageMultiply[mm, RGBColor[0, 0, 1, .5]]]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Updated

Simply use `{u, v} ∈ reg` in the parametric domain is faster enough!

```
reg = MengerMesh[5, DataRange -> {{-8, 8}, {0, 2 π}}];
surf = ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Cos[v], 
   Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Sin[v], -u}, {u, v} ∈ reg, PlotPoints -> 80,
   MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &)]
dissurf = surf // DiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

**Original**

Not so faster,but it can be `DiscretizeGraphics` or export to `stl` format with holes.

```
reg = TransformedRegion[
   MengerMesh[
    4], {Rescale[Indexed[#, 1], {0, 1}, {-8, 8}], 
     Rescale[Indexed[#, 2], {0, 1}, {0, 2 π}]} &];
(* Show[reg,Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red],FaceForm[],Rectangle[{-8,0},{8,2\
π}]}]] *)
surf = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Cos[v], 
   Sqrt[u^2 - 1] Sin[v], -u}, {u, -8, 8}, {v, 0, 2 π}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, RegionMember[reg, {u, v}]], 
  PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Mesh -> False, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &)]
dissurf = surf // DiscretizeGraphics
```